# Android SharedPreferences backup

Tags: android, key, backup, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to back up my app data using `SharedPreferencesBackupHelper`. As I understand it you first start by calling

```
SharedPreferencesBackupHelper helper = new SharedPreferencesBackupHelper(this, "KEY1", "KEY2");
```

My problem is that I'm doing a list application and there I back up the data for each list item using a separate key. That is a `String` combined with an `int`. It looks something like this:

```
spEdit.putString(Integer.toString(5) + "KEY_FOR_THIS", "value");
```

The 5 in the example can of course change and can be any number depending on how many items the user has added. Is there some good way to do this with a `for` loop for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key you pass to `SharedPreferencesBackupHelper`'s constructor isn't the key for a `Preference` inside your `SharedPreferences`: it's the name of the `SharedPreferences` file. That is, it's the `String` you pass to [`Context.getSharedPreferences(String,int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences%28java.lang.String,%20int%29). If you create your SharedPreferences file by calling [`Activity.getPreferences(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getPreferences%28int%29), you should pass the class name of that Activity.